# Añadir IVA a un articulo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo una tabla a la cual quiero sumarle el IVA al momento de ver lo que tengo, luego de haber asignado el valor, como puedo traer una operación que tengo en el modelo y pasarla al controlador y así mismo aplicarla en el `index`, tengo esto:

**index:**

```
<td><%= articulo.valor;@articulo.sumar_iva %></td>
```

**controlador:**

```
def iva
  @articulo = articulo_params
end
```

**modelo:**

```
def sumar_iva
  valor = self.valor*0.30 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas crear el objeto `Articulo` correctamente en el controlador para que todos los métodos del modelo están disponibles; por ejemplo:

```
def iva
  @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])
end
```

- Asumo que en los parámetros estás enviando el `id` del artículo sobre el cual quieres obtener el iva.

Para *sumar* el iva al valor, podrías simplemente multiplicar por 1.30 (en lugar de 0.30) dentro del método `sumar_iva`:

```
def sumar_iva
  self.valor * 1.30 
end
```

Ahora solo necesitas llamar el `@articulo.sumar_iva` en tu vista:

```
<td><%= @articulo.sumar_iva %></td>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me a servido el metodo, estoy aprendiendo y aveces me demoro mucho resolviendo esos pequeños problemas